# What is the difference between "every time I look outside my window" and "every time I look out my window"?

Tags: sentence

is there any difference between 
I am amazed by the view every time "I look outside my window" or "I look out my window" ?

I don't think there is any but "I look out my window" is more common.

Thank you.

Comment: I think "I look out my window" is the usual phrase, meaning that you are inside and look through the window to the outside.  "I look outside my window" *could* be taken to mean you were standing outside the building and and were looking at the area that was outside the window in question.  But I don't think "look outside the window" is what you want to say.  Stick with "out" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of emphasis and perspective. Looking out a window, like looking through a window, emphasizes the look. Looking outside the window emphasizes the outside, the thing you're looking at.